# Using JS file from child theme instead of from parent

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to load the `init.js` from child theme and to unload the one from parent theme.

The result is that I now see on page styles from both files. Why the parent file isn't unloaded and how exactly I can unload it?

I have added in `/child-theme/function.php` this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpshout_dequeue_and_then_enqueue', 100 );

function wpshout_dequeue_and_then_enqueue() {
    // Dequeue (remove) parent theme script
    wp_dequeue_script( '/js/init.js' );

    // Enqueue replacement child theme script
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'modified_child_script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/init.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}
```

Both files are with same names and are in

```
parent-theme
-js/init.js
```

and

```
child-theme
-js/init.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A few issues here to begin with**

- You should be using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() for child themes and get_template_directory_uri() for parent themes instead of the get_bloginfo() functions. Latter is slower and uses the first two functions
- Scripts and styles should be deregistered AND and dequeued to remove them completely from queue
- Priority is important. You need to hook your function later to make sure that the styles and scripts are registered before you deregister them, otherwise it won't work.

**Solution:**

Copy the parent js file to your child theme and open it up and make the necessary changed. Save the file

Now you need to dequeue AND deregister the parent js file and then enqueue you new child theme js file

```html
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpshout_dequeue_and_then_enqueue', 100 );

function wpshout_dequeue_and_then_enqueue() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'parent-script-handle' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'parent-script-handle' );
    // Now the parent script is completely removed

    /*
     * Now enqueue you child js file, no need to register if you are not 
     * doing conditional loading
     */
    wp_enqueue_script( 'child-script-handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/init.js' );
    //Now we have done it correctly
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I still need to change `'parent-script-handle'` with `'js/init.js'`, right?

Comment: The key point to getting this to work is to make sure you match up the what is being used after the add_action in your parents theme. Sometimes wp_enqueue_scripts is being used and sometimes wp_footer, depending on files and theme.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand this correctly. Currently the parent file is loaded in footer but the child js file is loaded in the head. Are you mean this?

Comment: So, I need to find that part in the parent `function.php` and moved it to the child `function.php` then change that too or remove..?

Comment: I've got `Cannot redeclare register_js() (previously declared in wp-content/themes/theme-child/functions.php:18)` when I trying to move the function from parent `function.php`

Comment: you can redeclare the function on child theme. so you can get the solution

Comment: Managed to do it. I've added addition `wp_register_script(...)` to `wp_enqueue_script(...)` and changed add_action to be after the setup `add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wpshout_dequeue_and_then_enqueue', 1);`

Comment: means you have changed the priority position. right?

Comment: As I understand it means that functions.php from the parent themes overwrites your settings of the child them, because it is loaded after your code. So, with the action `after_setup_theme` the function is loaded after the theme is initialized according to https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme